# Bash script vs command line

Tags: command-line, script, bash-scripting, sh

I have started working on bash scripts.
I have just observed a difference between executing a command line and executing the same commands but inside a script. In particular the command line is:

```
for a in {2..10..2};do echo "My number is:$a";done
```

which produces the following and expected output:

```
My number is:2
My number is:4
My number is:6
My number is:8
My number is:10
```

On the other hand, the script `test.sh` is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                      

for a in {2..10..2};do echo "My number is:$a";done
```

For this reason when I do:

```
./test.sh
```

I get the following output:

```
My number is:{2..10..2}
```

I would have expected these two approaches to be equivalent.

Why are these two approaches different and how can I obtain a proper use of the loop/curly bracket in order to get the same output as the command line?

Comment: Your script is not necessarily a `bash` script since `/bin/sh` is linked to different shells in different distributions. It it is linked to `/bin/bash`, then all bash extensions to POSIX are disabled. Change your shebang to `/bin/bash` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Understood. Please post this into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not necessarily a `bash` script since `/bin/sh` is linked to different shells in different distributions. It it is linked to `/bin/bash`, then all bash extensions to POSIX are disabled. Change your shebang to `/bin/bash` to get the behavior you want